# I need to know how to write my manifest.json file to deploy my application on oracle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, deployment

Initialized application creation...

Acquired resources for instance(2G) web.1...

Acquired resources for instance(2G) web.2...

Failed to deploy application(v1) for instance(2G) web.1...

Application is not running. Following are application logs 2018-03-29T00:59:27.429357+00:00 ACCS[web.1]: drwxr-xr-x 1 apaas apaas 46 Mar 29 00:58 .....

2018-03-29T00:59:27.430904+00:00 ACCS[web.1]: Starting application with launch command [ ruby app.rb ]

2018-03-29T00:59:27.466311+00:00 APP[web.1]: ruby: No such file or directory -- app.rb (LoadError)

2018-03-29T00:59:40.674751+00:00 ACCS[web.1]: "Content of APP_HOME [ /u01/app ] dir "

2018-03-29T00:59:40.676669+00:00 ACCS[web.1]: total 0

2018-03-29T00:59:40.676752+00:00 ACCS[web.1]: drwxr-xr-x 1 apaas apaas 192 Mar 28 02:31 bitview

2018-03-29T00:59:40.676804+00:00 ACCS[web.1]: drwxr-xr-x 1 apaas apaas 14 Mar 29 00:58 .

2018-03-29T00:59:40.676878+00:00 ACCS[web.1]: drwxr-xr-x 1 apaas apaas 46 Mar 29 00:58 ..

2018-03-29T00:59:40.678051+00:00 ACCS[web.1]: Starting application with launch command [ ruby app.rb ]

2018-03-29T00:59:40.713732+00:00 APP[web.1]: ruby: No such file or directory -- app.rb (LoadError)

Log-URL: [https://gse00014896.us.storage.oraclecloud.com/v1/Storage-gse00014896/_apaas/testrun/logsV2/4157996400_web.1_538e60cd_2018-03-29-010000_cust_server.out.zip]

App Summary - Name:[testrun], Identity domain: [idcs-f2b25b3358db4bd7a23ab81ff93845e1], Service Entitlement:[595583085], Compute Site:[US006_Z55]

For the complete application log, refer to log URL

Failed to deploy application(v1) for instance(2G) web.2...

Application is not running. Following are application logs 2018-03-29T00:59:26.758054+00:00 ACCS[web.2]: drwxr-xr-x 1 apaas apaas 46 Mar 29 00:58 .....

2018-03-29T00:59:26.759390+00:00 ACCS[web.2]: Starting application with launch command [ ruby app.rb ]

2018-03-29T00:59:26.794616+00:00 APP[web.2]: ruby: No such file or directory -- app.rb (LoadError)

2018-03-29T00:59:39.974943+00:00 ACCS[web.2]: "Content of APP_HOME [ /u01/app ] dir "

2018-03-29T00:59:39.977470+00:00 ACCS[web.2]: total 0

2018-03-29T00:59:39.977618+00:00 ACCS[web.2]: drwxr-xr-x 1 apaas apaas 192 Mar 28 02:31 bitview

2018-03-29T00:59:39.977749+00:00 ACCS[web.2]: drwxr-xr-x 1 apaas apaas 14 Mar 29 00:58 .

2018-03-29T00:59:39.977890+00:00 ACCS[web.2]: drwxr-xr-x 1 apaas apaas 46 Mar 29 00:58 ..

2018-03-29T00:59:39.979596+00:00 ACCS[web.2]: Starting application with launch command [ ruby app.rb ]

2018-03-29T00:59:40.015352+00:00 APP[web.2]: ruby: No such file or directory -- app.rb (LoadError)

App Summary - Name:[testrun], Identity domain: [idcs-f2b25b3358db4bd7a23ab81ff93845e1], Service Entitlement:[595583085], Compute Site:[US006_Z55]

For the complete application log, refer to log URL

Log-URL: [https://gse00014896.us.storage.oraclecloud.com/v1/Storage-gse00014896/_apaas/testrun/logsV2/4157996401_web.2_b475cb31_2018-03-29-005959_cust_server.out.zip]

Failed to create application...

Comment: This is the basic one i found online that was used for this deployment    {
  "runtime":{
     "majorVersion":"2.4.1"
},
  "command": "ruby app.rb",
  "mode": "rolling"
}

Answer (score 0):

For a basic app you don't need much, there's an example here 
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/apaas/ruby/ruby-getting-started/ruby-getting-started.html

```
{
  "runtime":{
    "majorVersion":"2.4.1"
  },
  "command": "ruby app.rb",
  "release": {},
  "notes": "Ruby Hello World"
}
```

substitute `app.rb` with whatever the name of your main file is. 
What you can do if you need to install gems or something is call a shell script instead with `sh start.sh` and (in the same directory) have a shell file like so

```
#!/bin/env sh

gem install rails
ruby app.rb
```

I hope this helps! :smiley: